# Command to parse through xml and JS files and output javaScript libraries being imported

Tags: awk, grep

Here is the cmd I have that is somewhat working. I'd also like to add the file path to the output.

```
find . \( -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.js' \) \( -type f -not -path "static" -type f -not -path "node_modules" \) -exec awk '/[require|define]\(\[/,/] | require\((.*)\)/'  {} \;
```

Previously i had two separate commands running for the two different styles of imports. Now that i put it in one command and separated the regex with | i get the following which also includes the function(mvc, Config) {...

```
require([
    'mvc',
    'config',
    'mvc/xml/ready!'
], function(mvc, Config) {

    var unsubmittedTokens = mvc.Components.getInstance('default');
    var submittedTokens = mvc.Components.getInstance('submitted');

    var username = Config['USERNAME'];
    unsubmittedTokens.set('currentUser', username);
    submittedTokens.set('currentUser', username);

});
```

Desired output is below. Note how there are two different styles of require statements. If one style of require statement is found in a file I'd like to skip and go to the next file which i think the | part of the regex should be doing.

```
/path-to-file
# require('copy-webpack-plugin')
```

```
/path-to-file
# require([
#    'jquery',
#    'underscore',
#    'backbone',
#    'bootstrap.affix',
#    'bootstrap.scrollspy'
# ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the awk part to this:

```sh
 awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","} FNR == 1 {print FILENAME} /[require|define]\(\[/,/]/ {print "# " $1} /require\((.*)\)/ {print "# " $1}'  {} \;
```

And got this output:

```sh
/file1.js
# require([
#     'mvc'
#     'config'
#     'mvc/xml/ready!'
# ]
/file2.js
# require('mvc',
```

Comment: Here's a case where it looks like it went past the require statement and on to the instantiation of CopyWebpackPlugin where it found the ([ instead of stopping at require('copy-webpack-plugin');   
``` lang-js                                                    
# var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
#         new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
#             from: path.join(appDir
```

Comment: In the awk cmd is there a way to only print out JS imports that would be found in a "whitelist" array? If the JS import can be found in the whitelist array print it out, if not don't.

Comment: Well, It depends a little bit on how well you can capture the whitelists of course. but you could pipe awk scripts into each other like this: `cat yourfiles | awk '/BEGIN_WHITELIST/, /END_WHITELIST/' | awk '<gets require statements>'`.

Comment: -exec cat output_web.json | awk '/BEGIN_WHITELIST/, /END_WHITELIST/' | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","} FNR == 1 {print FILENAME} /[require|define]\(\[/,/]/ {print "# " $1} /require\((.*)\)/ {print "# " $1}'  {} \;

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not explicitly state it. but you have to write the regex to determine the whitelist yourself. I don't know how the file looks like. my point was that `awk '<start pattern>, <end pattern>'` will return the whitelists in your file. which you can than  pipe into another awk expression.

Comment: The output_web.json file itself contains the strings that are considered the white list in an array format like below

Comment: [
    "svg/SVGUtils",
    "svg/VizIcons"]

Comment: Been trying the below which i think is getting close but getting some errors

Comment: find . \( -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.js' \) \( -type f -not -path "static" -type f -not -path "node_modules" \) -exec  awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","} FNR == 1 {print FILENAME} /[require|define]([/,/]/ {print "# " $1} /require((.*))/ | awk '{ m=0 ; while ((getline row < "output_web.json") == 1) { if (row == $0) { m=1 ; break } } ; close("output_web.json") ; if (m == 0) { print $0 }}' \;